# Should I make my database class static

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, static

In an ASP web project I have a class 'SQL' class to handle the connection with the database.

In the class I use no fields or propperties

Every method has a structure similar to this :

```
try
    {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GlobalSettings.Connections.ConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();

               //dostuff with connection
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Log.GenericLog(String.Format("SQL Exception message - {0}. Exception stacktrace - {1}", e.Message,
                e.StackTrace));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.GenericLog(String.Format("Exception message - {0}. Exception stacktrace - {1}", e.Message,
                e.StackTrace));
        }
```

Is it safe to use a static class here?

Comment: It depends on what `"//dostuff with connection"` does, if it maintains state then there are thread safety considerations.  Mainstream databases implement Connection Pooling automatically allowing you to efficiently create connections as and when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static class if you like. However think about testability. How easy will this be to test when it is static. How easy will the rest of your code be to test that has a reference to this static class. Why not use the repository pattern as an abstraction over your data access more testable. Then you will want to inject the data access code and a static class won't cut the mustard.

Comment: I agree, although you are 'safe' to use static, its not considered best practice